# Mean log determinant of a random Gaussian matrix

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, random-matrices

I wish to calculate the mean log determinant of a random Gaussian matrix, defined by the following definite integral (for $a, b, \sigma\in\mathbb{R}$):
$$
I(a, b, \sigma) = \int \frac{d^{n \times n}X}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{n^2}} e^{-\sum_{i,j}^nX_{ij}^2/2\sigma^2-\frac{1}{2}\log\det(aX+bI)}
$$

Bonus: allow for a linear term, defined by $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$:
$$
I = \int \frac{d^{n \times n}X}{\sqrt{2\pi}^{n^2}} e^{-\sum_{i,j}^nX_{ij}^2/2\sigma^2+\sum_{i,j}^nA_{ij}X_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}\log\det(aX+bI)}
$$

[Random matrices: Law of the determinant](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0752.pdf) provides a CLT-like result for the distribution of the log determinant of X when $n\to\infty$ and assuming $\sigma=1, A=0, b=0, a=1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\int d^{n\times n} X \ldots $ rather than $d^{n\times n} X \int \ldots$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: sure, thanks!!

Comment: I am a little confused. Are you asking about the value of $\mathbb{E}[\log \det(aX + bI)]$ when the entries of $X$ are iid $N(0, \sigma^2)$? Or are you asking about, as your current question indicates, $\mathbb{E}[\det(aX + bI)^{-1/2}]$?

Comment: Also, in the linked paper, they are giving results for $\log | \det \cdot|$ --- note the modulus.

Comment: @DrewBrady the math description is the correct one, not the verbal title.

Comment: It looks like your expression asks for the average of $\prod_i(a\lambda_i+b)^{-1/2}$ where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $X$. Apparently the random Gaussian matrix is called the Ginibre ensemble, for complex valued $X$ the pdf of the eigenvalues is known, and for real $X$ it seems the pdf is given [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.2020). I'm not sure if that helps. It may be useful to use the bound $\text{tr}(\mathbb{I}-A^{-1})\leq \ln \det A\leq\text{tr}(A-\mathbb{I})$, which would entail using the pdf of the entries for $A^{-1}$...

Comment: you can always try randomly generating them and see what the value seems to converge to? To get a hint of where to start I mean.